# How to create 2 actions with same path but different HTTP methods DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So I'm trying to have different actions under the same method, but the last defined method is the only one that work, is there a way to do this?

**views.py**

```
class SomeViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    ...

    @detail_route(methods=['post'])
    def methodname(self, request, pk=None):
    ... action 1

    @detail_route(methods=['get'])
    def methodname(self, request, pk=None):
    ... action 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to have actions based on HTTP request type? like for post request execute action 1 and for get request execute action 2? If that's the case then try

```
def methodname(self, request, pk=None):
    if request.method == "POST":
        action 1..
    else 
        action 2..
```

Answer (score 13):

The most rational method I've found [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/pull/5605):

```
class MyViewSet(ViewSet):
    @action(detail=False)
    def example(self, request, **kwargs):
        """GET implementation."""

    @example.mapping.post
    def create_example(self, request, **kwargs):
        """POST implementation."""
```

That method provides possibility to use `self.action` inside of another viewset methods with correct value.

Comment: In the documentation [Routing additional HTTP methods for extra actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#routing-additional-http-methods-for-extra-actions)